# Understanding the meaning of this c# code

Tags: c#, google-tasks-api

I'm trying to understand the following code:

```
  flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
  {
    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Tasks.ASP.NET.Sample.Store"),
    ClientSecretsStream = stream,
    Scopes = new[] { TasksService.Scope.TasksReadonly }
  });
```

From my understanding, the code between the first and last {...} is the body of an anonymous function. The new FileDataStore creates a new instance of FileDataStore. What I don't understand is what the comma at the end of it means. The two lines following it also have commas at the end. What kind of construct is this called in C#? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: This is called [*Object initializer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it isn't the body of an anonymous function. It is an *initialization list*.. and it serves to set the fields of the new object of type `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer` all in-line.

It is the "in-line" version of this:

```
var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer();
initializer.DataStore = new FileDataStore("Tasks.ASP.NET.Sample.Store");
initializer.ClientSecretsStream = stream;
initializer.Scopes = new[] { TasksService.Scope.TasksReadonly };

flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer);
```

The two are equivalent functionally. It is just more compact.

Comment: What you wrote above is what I am more familiar with. What version of c# was this inline introduced in? Any idea? I don't recall it being in earlier versions. I actually like the longer method. Easier on the eyes :-)

Comment: @AndroidDev Object and collection initializers were introduced in [C# 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx) (March 2007).

Answer (score 3):

It's a constructor initializer.
The code is creating a new `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer` object, and setting `DataStore`, `ClientSecretsStream` and `Scopes` properties on the object.

This is then being passed to a `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` constructor as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have a class Sample.

```
public class Sample()
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int key { get; set; }
}
```

This can be initialized as

```
var sample = new Sample {id = 1, key = "one"};
```

Then pass this `sample` as argument.

In your example they have done same thing to the parameter. This is called as class initializer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this the same thing as a class constructor where you can have parameters in the constructor?

Comment: In your example `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` constructor needs an instance of `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer` object/class. As I see `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer` has a parameter less constructor. You code snippet is creating the class instance using class initializer and passing this as a parameter. Hope it was clear now.